# Using Scrapy Selenium Middleware on heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, scrapy

I'm using scrapy selenium https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-selenium/ to drive my spiders and i have it hosted on Heroku. 
My challenge is that i can't seem to get around how to configure the paths to find the chromedriver and also the chrome binary that heroku needs to run the app

I have my environments setup and i have my buildpacks installed

**BuildPacks**

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
```

**Enviroments setup in my config variable of heroku**

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_PATH = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google_chrome'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
```

Where i get lost is now how to configure my above settings to work with this option in my settings.py file of my spider

```
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('geckodriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless'] # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
```

It works perfectly on my local machine by using this settings

```
chrome_path = "/Users/username/chromepath/chromedriver"

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome' # Change to your browser name
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = chrome_path
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
```

I found some solutions on the internet but they would only work if i was using webdriver to get the request.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

So my question now is how to i setup scrapy-selenium paths to work with my enviroments on heroku

Comment: Do you have a traceback or error message you can post to help us resolve your issue?

Comment: i think i made some progress
I used the following settings in my settings.py
`SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome' # Change to your browser name`
`SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")`
`SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless','--no-sandbox','--disable-dev-shm-usage',] # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox`
The error line is : selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5

Comment: @ThePyGuy The process got clearer after i went through the Selenium Request Middleware Docs [https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/blob/develop/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py] but now i'm stuck at chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was -5

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you might have solved this, but for the sake of someone else that might be looking for this solution.

```
import os

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'

SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = CHROMEDRIVER_PATH 

SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless', "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"]

SELENIUM_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN", "chromedriver")
```

This setting deployed my selenium_scrapy script successfully. But damn, I suffered prior to this fix.
cheers